# Why would the param_type constructor be explicit for a random distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, std, explicit

I'm trying to compile this program (see it live [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z040MmKP6ktjSBFg)):

```
int main() {
  std::random_device engine;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dis;
  std::cout << dis(engine, {0, 5}) << std::endl;
}
```

But it fails with the error message:

```
error: converting to 'const std::uniform_int_distribution<long unsigned int>::param_type' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>::param_type::param_type(_IntType, _IntType) [with _IntType = long unsigned int]'
   std::cout << dis(engine, {0, 5}) << std::endl;
```

Obviously, it is the explicit constructor of `param_type` that prevents us from doing this. But why specifying it as explicit in the first place? It's verbose and silly if one has to write

```
std::cout << dis(engine, decltype(dis)::param_type(0, 5)) << std::endl;
```

Any explanations on this? And also, how could I achieve what I want in a succinct and elegant way, given that the `param_type` constructor is explicit in the standard? Note that, in practice, the range may be different each time I invoke `dis`. So, supplying a range at the construction time of `dis` does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is explicit because it has defaulted arguments.  Any constructor taking 1 argument that isn't intended to be a converting constructor should be explicit.

Because the standard mandates one constructor with two defaulted arguments, all cases are explicit.  An improvement would be to mandate a 2 argument constructor that is not explicit, an explicit 1 argument constructor, and a non-explicit 0 argument constructor.  But that ship has sailed.

We can work around your problem.

```
template<class...Args>
struct construct_params_t {
  std::tuple<Args&&...> data;
  construct_params_t(Args&&...args):data(std::forward<Args>(args)...){}

private:
  template<class T, std::size_t...Is>
  T create( std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
    return T( std::get<Is>(std::move(data))... );
  }
public:
  template<class T>
  operator T()&&{
    return create<T>( std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{} );
  }
};
template<class...Args>
construct_params_t<Args...> construct_from(Args&&...args) {
  return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

now you can do:

```
int main() {
  std::random_device engine;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> dis;
  std::cout << dis(engine, construct_from(0, 5)) << std::endl;
}
```

basically, `construct_from(a,b,c)` can be used to construct almost anything, and it does so explicitly, without having to mention its name when constructing it.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2feed53ad9a3d537).

The objects thus constructed must be movable, and with RVO elision it shouldn't actually move them.

Storing the return value of `construct_from` is not advised.

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't make much sense for `param_type` constructor to have default arguments. Typically, the need to use `param_type` simply implies that the defaults do not apply. The `construct_from()` you designed is hackish, and yes, I do like tricky C++ stuff :) I will put it into my [Happy Hacking C++](https://github.com/Lingxi-Li/Happy_Hacking_CXX) project. But for practical use, I will just stick to `decltype(...)::param_type`.